# determinant of 2×2 symmetric matrix

Tags: determinant, symmetric-matrices

> Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ symmetric  matrix.
>   If there are $2$-dimensional vectors $x,y$ with same size such that $Ax=ry$ and $x\perp y$, then $\det A = r^2$.
>   This can be shown by elementwise computation.

Is there any good generalization of this, with respect to dimension?